# Concatenate all text files recursively in a directory where the closest parent directory's name has a certain string in its name

Tags: batch-file, recursion, merge

I'm trying to write a batch script that concatenates all text files that resides in a directory with a name containing a certain string recursively.

In the example below the files marked with an (x) should be merged since their closest parent directory's name has a name including the STRING

```
Directory
|-- STRINGdirectory2
|    |-- textfile.txt       (x)
|    |-- anotherfile.txt    (x)
|-- anotherdirectory2
|    |-- textfile.txt
|-- directory3
|    |-- STRINGdirectory3
|    |    |-- file.txt      (x)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? 
Do you mean put all of them in one directory or do you mean concatenate?

Comment: @rep_movsd I want to concatenate them. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=c:\somewhere\Directory"

    (   for /r "%root%" /d %%a in ("*string*") do (
            for %%b in ("%%~fa\*.txt") do (
                type "%%~fb"
                echo(
            )
        )
    ) >"%root%\concatenated.txt" 2>nul
```

Given a root folder, for each folder under it that contains the indicated string in its name, for each txt file inside the folder, type the file

The full `for` output is redirected to a file to hold the "concatenated" data.

Comment: Great! How do I add a newline after each addition?

Comment: Shouldnt it be 
set root=c:\somewhere\Directory rather than 
set "root=c:\somewhere\Directory"

Comment: @rep_movsd - Either can work, but the quoted version is better because it prevents inadvertent trailing spaces from getting into the value.

Comment: Nice! You even have the `echo(` to add a newline between files, just in case the last line is missing \r\n. The only improvement would be to add the \r\n conditionally, but that would be difficult with pure batch. My [JREPL utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) would work well - replace TYPE with `jrepl "$(?!\r?\n)" "\r\n" /m /x /f "%%~fb"`

Answer (score 1):

[MC ND has a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29513533/1012053) that properly handles the possibility that the last line in a file may not have a line terminator (\n or \r\n). If he didn't have the ECHO(, then the first line of a file could be appended to the last line of the previous file if it did not have the line terminator. The only issue with MC ND's answer is it can add an extra blank line between files even when not needed.

If you know that all your files have a line terminator at the end, then there is a really simple solution that relies on undocumented [wildcard characters](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39420#p39420), and the fact that [undocumented wildcards used with FINDSTR do not trigger output of file name prefixes](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39464#p39464).

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\your\root\path"
>concatenated.txt 2>nul (for /r /d %%D in (*string*) do findstr "^" "<.txt")
```

If you know that some files might be missing the final line terminator, but all files use the Windows standard \r\n line terminator, then you can use the following to conditionally add the line terminator between files only as needed. The FINDSTR command checks to see if the file contains a line that does not contain \r (carriage return).

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\your\root\path"
>concatenated.txt 2>nul (
  for /r /d %%D in (*string*) do for %%F in ("%%D\*.txt) do (
    type "%%F"
    findstr /v "$" "%%F" >nul && echo(
  )
)
```

If you know that some files might be missing the final line terminator, and you think some files might use \n instead of \r\n, then you can use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) to conditionally append \r\n only as needed. JREPL.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\your\root\path"
>concatenated.txt 2>nul (
  for /r /d %%D in (*string*) do for %%F in ("%%D\*.txt) do (
    jrepl "$(?~\r?\n)" "\r\n" /m /x /f "%%F"
  )
)
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions where I usually to wait for your response using `jrepl` as it is the obvious tool for the work, but in this case i didn't realize it could be used. Really nice. But i still disagree with the *"undocumented"* term.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET tempfile=%temp%\%RANDOM% 

if '%1' == '' goto usage
if '%2' == '' goto usage
if '%3' == '' goto usage

if exist %3 del %3
dir /S /B | find %2 > %tempfile%

if '%4' == 'test' goto dryrun

for /F %%i in (temp.txt) do type %%i >> "%3"

goto end

:dryrun
type %tempfile%
goto end

:usage

echo Usage %0 ^<dir^> ^<pattern^> ^<destination^> [test]
echo   Concatente all files inside ^<dir^> whose names have the substring ^<pattern^> into ^<destination^>
echo   Specify 'test' optionally the fourth argument for a dry run which will merely list the files

:end
if exist %tempfile% del %tempfile%
```